# Fetch request returns cors and shows twice in Network tab of Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

After doing a fetch() request, the first request listed shows a **204 Fetch** and the second listed entry shows **200 json** in the Network tab of Chrome DevTools. Why are there two listings for 1 fetch() request?

Within my app, the fetch() returns a `Response { type: 'cors', url: '...', status: 200, statusText: "OK" }` but when I click on the second entry and view the response within DevTools, I see the data returned. Why is it then that within my app, I'm getting a 'cors' response and not the data?

The headers that I'm passing are authorization headers to a restify back-end that will allow cors access if these headers are present.

```
return fetch(`${urls[process.env.NODE_ENV]}/test`, { headers })
      .then(result => dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(result.data)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchDataError(error)));
```

Comment: are you fetching from different domain than the domain your website is served from?

Comment: They're both on localhost but different ports, so yes. However, the headers that I'm passing are authorization headers to a restify back-end that will allow cors access if these headers are present. So this shouldn't be an issue I think.

Comment: Your backend support cors, so the cors request pass with 200. Since it is a cross domain request, a extra cors request is needed before browser will fetch actual request. That is what you are seeing, and won't happen if it is under same domain

Comment: Ok, but how come I get a 'cors' response inside my app but in Chrome DevTools I see the correct data returned?

Comment: One of the items in the inspector should be an OPTIONS request to get cors information, and the other will be the original request type (probably POST). Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm not seeing the OPTIONS request. Why would that be?